# Computing a limit for the Weierstrass function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, cv.complex-variables

Let $a\in (0,1)$ and let $b$ be an odd positive integer such that $ab>1+\frac{3}{2}\pi$. Let $\alpha \in (0,1)$ be defined by $\alpha= -\frac{ln(a)}{ln(b)}$ and consider the well known Weierstrass function
$$ W_\alpha(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b^{-n\alpha}\cos(b^n\pi x).$$

It is well known that $W_\alpha \in C^\alpha(\mathbb R)$ in the sense that
$$ |W_\alpha(x)-W_\alpha(y)| \leq C |x-y|^\alpha$$
for all $x,y$.

**Question.** Compute the following limit.
$$ \lim_{y\to x} \frac{|W_\alpha(y)-W_\alpha(x)|}{|y-x|^\alpha}.$$

Thanks,